# Wrike Redirect URI is invalid

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

First I have this link

```
https://www.wrike.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<?php echo WRIKE_CLIENT_ID; ?>&response_type=code&redirect_uri=<?php echo urlencode(WRIKE_RETURN_URL); ?>
```

when we click on the url it redirect me to the WRIKE_RETURN_URL

But when I'm trying to connect to connect to the wrike API, on the redirected page I have the error below

My code on the redirected page is like this

```
        $fields = [
            'client_id'     => WRIKE_CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret' => WRIKE_CLIENT_SECRET,
            'grant_type'    => 'authorization_code',                            
            'code'          => $code,
        ];
```

the $code variable, I get by $_GET['code'] of the url

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.wrike.com/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
```

I keep getting the error :

```
{ ["error"]=> string(13) "invalid_grant" ["error_description"]=> string(23) "Redirect URI is invalid" }
```

Comment: Can you show us your `$fields` array?

Comment: I did please see the post , I edited the post.

Comment: Are you sure, code and result match? `redirect uri` is part of step 1, your code shows step 3 from the docs: https://developers.wrike.com/documentation/oauth2

Comment: I don't know i understand you but I edited the post again, and explained what I did step by step